# Ficheros configuracion no se borran en Android 9

Tags: android

Tengo un dispositivo Samsung S8 que se actualizó a Android 9. 
Hasta Android 8 si desintalaba una app que tenía un fichero de configuración guardado en memoria_Interna/Android/data/ todos los ficheros desaparecian y si volvia a instalar la misma app no habia ninguna información guardada.

Desde que se actualizó a Android 9, después de haber borrado todos los datos y el cache de la app y desintalar la app, si vuelvo a instalar la misma app me aparecen los datos de configuración que tenía antes de de la desinstalación.

Al desarrollar apps y actualizarlas, esto me pude generar problemas.

En un dispositivo S6 con Android 8, esto no ocurre.

¿Porqué ocurre esto y donde se han guardado esos datos?.
¿Como puedo hacer una instalación limpia desde cero?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que configuración tienes definida en tu AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

eso se debe a que android tiene [AutoBackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup) lo que hace que guarde automaticamente algunos datos como las sharedPreferences o algunos ficheros.

Si te parece que esto es peligroso para el normal funcionamiento de tu app. Puedes simplemente desactivar el backup usando estos flags en el manifest:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

Comment: El Autobackup funciona igual en todas la versiones anteriores a android 9, el usuario indica que en android 8 el problema no ocurre.

Comment: No, autobackup tuvo una actualizacion en android 9 exactamente. En la cual se le puede agregar reglas de backup, si esta aplicacion tiene agregado un archivo de backup_rules entonces solo se usara el backup en android 9 en adelante por cuestiones de seguridad segun entiendo.

Comment: Deberías preguntar al OP sobre esta configuración ya que de otra forma estamos suponiendo que tiene este cuando puede ser por otra causa.

Comment: @Jorgesys entonces cual crees que es el problema?

Comment: No tengo desactivado el AutoBackup en el manifest. En principio esto no supone un problema para mi app, pero en caso necesario ¿Como se pueden borrar esos ficheros? . Gracias

Comment: Entiendo que no, porque Android lo guarda aun si desinstalas la app o borras los datos o incluso si borras la cache.